# Converting Text to CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have a product reviews text file which I want to convert to CSV for data analysis. Below is part of how the text file looks like:

```
Id:   1
ASIN: 0827229534
  title: Patterns of Preaching: A Sermon Sampler
  group: Book
  salesrank: 396585
  similar: 5  0804215715  156101074X  0687023955  0687074231  082721619X
  categories: 2
   |Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Religion & Spirituality[22]|Christianity[12290]|Clergy[12360]|Preaching[12368]
   |Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Religion & Spirituality[22]|Christianity[12290]|Clergy[12360]|Sermons[12370]
  reviews: total: 2  downloaded: 2  avg rating: 5
    2000-7-28  cutomer: A2JW67OY8U6HHK  rating: 5  votes:  10  helpful:   9
    2003-12-14  cutomer: A2VE83MZF98ITY  rating: 5  votes:   6  helpful:   5

Id:   2
ASIN: 0738700797
  title: Candlemas: Feast of Flames
  group: Book
  salesrank: 168596
  similar: 5  0738700827  1567184960  1567182836  0738700525  0738700940
  categories: 2
   |Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Religion & Spirituality[22]|Earth-Based Religions[12472]|Wicca[12484]
   |Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Religion & Spirituality[22]|Earth-Based Religions[12472]|Witchcraft[12486]
  reviews: total: 12  downloaded: 12  avg rating: 4.5
    2001-12-16  cutomer: A11NCO6YTE4BTJ  rating: 5  votes:   5  helpful:   4
    2002-1-7  cutomer:  A9CQ3PLRNIR83  rating: 4  votes:   5  helpful:   5
    2002-1-24  cutomer: A13SG9ACZ9O5IM  rating: 5  votes:   8  helpful:   8
    2002-1-28  cutomer: A1BDAI6VEYMAZA  rating: 5  votes:   4  helpful:   4
    2002-2-6  cutomer: A2P6KAWXJ16234  rating: 4  votes:  16  helpful:  16
    2002-2-14  cutomer:  AMACWC3M7PQFR  rating: 4  votes:   5  helpful:   5
    2002-3-23  cutomer: A3GO7UV9XX14D8  rating: 4  votes:   6  helpful:   6
    2002-5-23  cutomer: A1GIL64QK68WKL  rating: 5  votes:   8  helpful:   8
    2003-2-25  cutomer:  AEOBOF2ONQJWV  rating: 5  votes:   8  helpful:   5
    2003-11-25  cutomer: A3IGHTES8ME05L  rating: 5  votes:   5  helpful:   5
    2004-2-11  cutomer: A1CP26N8RHYVVO  rating: 1  votes:  13  helpful:   9
    2005-2-7  cutomer:  ANEIANH0WAT9D  rating: 5  votes:   1  helpful:   1
```

How do I turn that into a CSV?

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: This is a parsing problem, not a conversion-to-CSV problem.  In order to create a CSV, you need to define fields for each row.  If each row is a product, the fields will be details such as title, group, etc... Some of the data, like categories, similar products, or reviews are lists containing additional structure.  This might be better organized into multiple CSV files or database tables.  Forcing this hierarchical data into a single flat CSV can create unnecessary work and hassle for yourself or other people in later steps of the analysis as most existing tools only work with simple fields.

Comment: @Paul - Thanks! got it.